# Duplicity with GPG 2.1

Tags: gnupg, duplicity

I am trying to configure daily backups from my computer to a remote server using duplicity, but for some reason duplicity does not want to cooperate with GPG at all. I have never consciously used GPG before and I am experiencing some behaviors which I do not understand.

I generated a key pair using gpg:

```
gpg --quick-gen-key myName
```

Then I use duplicity to backup some directory:

```
duplicity --encrypt-key myName some-directory file://backup
```

this seems to work fine because I get no errors.

if I now run the exact same command again, which should make an incremental backup and encrypt the increment with the same public key, I get the following gpg errors:

```
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: ebncrypted with 1024-bit RSA key, ID FA5B21B4E274D59A, created 2019-08-14 "myName"
gpg: public key decryption failed: No passphrase given
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I have looked around and found a [question about something similar on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/984977/duplicity-restore-failing-no-secret-key) but after creating and editing the gpg.conf and gpg-agent-conf files I am still getting the same errors.

Is anyone using duplicity with gpg keys succesfully and can tell me what I am doing wrong?

gpg version is 2.2.4 and duplicity 0.7.17.

Comment: I just noticed I'm getting this couple of errors as well and I'm not yet certain of the cause. Are you by any chance running that duplicity command as root?